# how to resolve the android out of memory exception?

Tags: android, bitmap

I was developed app, in this i have two activites one is PaintActivity and another one is TextActivity. when the user click the button in PaintActivity, TextActivity will be displayed along with the bitmap of PainActivity. In this user enter the text, and gives font style and color to the text after editing is done click the apply button to go to the paintactivity along with text and bitmap, i am using following code it works fine, except the one device,then i checked in different emulators, in one emulator(5.4"FWVGA(480*854:mdpi)) i get outofmemory exception when clicking the apply button in TextAcitivty.

I am using following code

PaintActivity:

```
text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             realPaint.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
             Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(realPaint.getDrawingCache());
            realPaint.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
             ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             b2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bs);
             byte[] byteArray = bs.toByteArray();
             Intent i=new Intent(PaintActivity.this, TextActivity.class);
             i.putExtra("bitT", byteArray);
             realPaint.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
           startActivityForResult(i,TEXT_BITMAP);
        }
    });

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

     if(requestCode==TEXT_BITMAP && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){
          byte[] byteArray=data.getByteArrayExtra("bittext");
          BitmapFactory.Options opt=new BitmapFactory.Options();
          opt.inSampleSize=3;
          Bitmap bittext=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length,opt);
          image.setImageBitmap(bittext);
    }
}
```

TextACtivity:

```
apply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        loadBitmapFromView(real).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bs);
        byte[] byteArray = bs.toByteArray();
        i.putExtra("bittext", byteArray);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reduce the size of the bitmaps by using another config - that is Config.RGB_565

```
 opt.inSampleSize=3;
 opt.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
```

Comment: I get the error in TextActivity class apply.setOnClickListener method

Comment: You could try to set heapsize to large in the manifestfile - that is within the application tag:  android:largeHeap="true". But its not the  best solution (always better to understand what part of the code that are exhausting memory).

Answer (score 0):

I am using a static bitmap instead  of sending the byte array(Converting the bitmap into byte array)to avoid the out of memory exception.